# Why is my active passband filter (LP and HP Butterworth filters in series) not working?

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, analog, active-filter, band-pass

[image: schematic of the circuit used]

I did each filter alone and they work fine, but when they are made together to form a bandpass filter with the same components I used they don't work.

The output on the oscilloscope is a very weak signal that is similar to the output signal when the circuit is not fed with electricity (I guess it's negligible environment noise) while the input is a sine function from the function generator. Am I missing a middle stage or something? I tried all frequencies from 1Hz to 3MHz and nothing changes, even changing the amplitude of the input has no effects.

Comment: Please add an image of the oscilloscope waveform, a picture of your setup, etc.

Comment: I think you meant to list the values as R2 and R3, rather than R4 and R3, but I don't know which is which.

Comment: is fc1 the lowpass or the highpass stage? Not clear from your R2/R4 error. If 50Hz is the lowpass, you've got a band reject filter.

Comment: Make sure the low pass cut-off frequency is higher in frequency than the high pass cut-off frequency. If they are switched there will be no output.

Comment: So your circuit: 1) rejects anything above 49 Hz and then 2) pass through anything above 497 Hz. So which of these frequencies can pass: 5 Hz, 200 Hz, 1 kHz?

Comment: Your circuit has no very important power supply voltages. The minimum recommended for a TL072 is +5V and -5V. Your circuit does not have R4, do you mean R2? Your filters are backwards, the highpass with a 47Hz cutoff should be at the input then the lowpass with a 497Hz cutoff should be at the output.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis 
R2=R4 sorry for my mistake

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie the 200 Hz should pass, but I'm not getting anything at the output except for random noisy signal and so low in amplitude.

Comment: @Neil_UK the 49Hz is in the high pass filter R2 is R4 I'm sorry

Comment: @James yes yes the high pass filter is 49 Hz and the low pass filter is 497Hz I just made the mistake of calling R2 R4, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @yahiaaymen so how about fixing up the diagram in your post? Correctly labelled FTW. Label each block with its corner frequency as well, rather than leaving us to guess which is fc1 and fc2.

Comment: *the 200 Hz should pass* I disagree, the first filter blocks everything above 49 Hz so how can 200 Hz pass? The second filter blocks anything below 497 Hz so again 200 Hz is blocked. You mean: I would like 200 Hz to pass. It does not because you mixed up the low-pass and high-pass frequencies.

Comment: For bandpass (or bandstop) filters whose corner frequencies are one decade (or so) or less you should construct them as bandpass (or bandstop), not lowpass+highpass, because the corner frequencies will be influenced. The bandpass automatically takes care of that since the poles (and/or zeroes) will be automatically shifted to match, but the lp+hp will be set in stone. [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIAYT.png) is an example with your lp+hp vs a clear bp. The scale is linear to better see that, while the lp+hp matches the -3 dB points, they have attenuated passband.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I'd love to if the solution for the Butterworth bandpass filter transfer function would give logical resistors values and not something negative or complex for the specific frequencies I want, and unfortunately, the flatness of the passe band is important to my application so I can't go choose another topology or design I know like Chebyshev or something...

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie even if it's a reject band filter it still didn't work since I tried all frequencies from 1 till 3MHz. 
and I don't think you got me R4 is R2, I'm quite sure I'm correct since I tried every part alone and they both functioned normally and as I expected them to do.

Comment: @Neil_UK I'd love to fix my diagram but I'm quite new to this website is there a way to edit the picture or something to correct my mistake?

Comment: @yahiaaymen Then if Butterworth is a fixed parameter in the design you're limited to flat, monotonic roll-off of a multiple of -20 dB/dec. All filters have this, but some roll-off faster initially, others slower, and yet others have zeroes and need a very large transition width in order to see the n*20 dB/dec. Also, Butterworth will not be optimal in terms of the filter order, so you'll be stuck with a low order (8, 10 max, probably), which means you'll have limited attenuation. There's no way around this, unless you decide to add zeroes to a Butterworth -- doable, but ruins the passband.

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I can worry about the design choices and flaws later, what matters to me right now is that this circuit is theoretically supposed to work but it's not working, to be honest with you in university we get a lot of theory but very few opportunities to practice and the result is? someone like me can do all the Laplace and Fourier calculations but can't realize a simple filter like this one :').

note: I appreciate your answer it opened my eyes to some theoretical details I used to ignore .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've switched the corners you intended to implement.

What you're looking to build is a bandpass filter between 49 - 497 Hz. In order to accomplish this, first you need a high pass filter at 49 Hz, which will eliminate all low frequencies. Then the output of that stage needs to be filtered with a low pass filter with a 497 Hz corner.

So, fix the corner frequencies and you should be in good shape.

Comment: does it matter which circuit is first? or did I switch between high pass and low pass cut-off frequencies?

Comment: You're right - the fact that the corners are switched is the only problem. I corrected my answer. Does it make sense now that the low pass corner needs to be higher than the high pass corner?

Comment: so why it didn't work as a reject band filter at least? all the frequencies that I tried were attenuated.

Comment: Band reject requires a different topology. You essentially have to bring the input signal to both filters and sum the outputs. Think of these two stages as the mathematical product of two functions. Once you filter out everything above 49 Hz it's gone. Then filtering that with a high pass filter eliminates all the signal that's left.

Comment: I just noticed that my mistake R4 is actually R2 in the schematic, my high pass filter is actually the one with cut-off frequency equals 49Hz. I'm so sorry if that made confusion.
in short, way the circuit is: filtering everything above 497Hz then filtering anything less than 49 Hz

Comment: When troubleshooting this issue, you can probe the output of the first stage to see what's going on. Perhaps there's an assembly or wiring issue. The first stage is drawn in a slightly confusing manner - make sure the output of the opamp isn't really grounded.

Comment: exactly and I tried to see the first stage output and it was the same signal at the output while it was functioning normally when it was alone in the circuit. I repeated the circuit many times trying to fix the issue, I'm used to it like the palm of my hand.

Comment: You can try testing the second stage by itself. There's something wrong but very difficult to tell from a distance. You can check power rails, component values, etc.

Comment: I did realize the second stage and first stage individually, and they work super fine, that's why I'm confused, I wanna know if there's some sort of adaptation that can be added between the two stages even if it's optional, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

### Supplemental info.

As you now know, the sequence of breakpoints makes a difference in attenuation , but not the sequence of cascading the same stages.  These are different filters.

See the difference is 40 dB in this case and a slight shift in the 0 deg phase.

[image]

Comment: but at least both ways of cascading are working normally except for the difference in performance. however, I got nothing at the output, just a very tiny noisy sine signal with max amplitude of less than 5 mV.

Comment: -40 dB or 1% ought to allow you to at least find which stage was lossy  . You can always check Vin + to ensure it matches Vin-.

Comment: sorry for being a slow learner, can you elaborate more? I don't think I understand what you mean.

Comment: When using non-inverting input the feedback signal matches that Vin+ to make a null error input. Then check each stage.. Using an FM< sig gen , use x output to sweep FM input